# MaterializeCSS modal events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Im trying to execute some stuff while the modal is opening but it wont fire the event at all.

```
  $('.modal').modal({
   onOpenStart: function(){
    console.log("it works!");
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>


<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try calling functions like this in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal').modal({
        onOpenStart() {
            console.log("Open Start");
        },
        onOpenEnd() {
            console.log("Open End");
        },
        onCloseStart(){
            console.log("Close Start");
        },
        onCloseEnd(){
            console.log("Close End");
        },
    });
});
```

Or if you want to do in vanillaJS then you can call them like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const optionsModal = {
            onOpenStart: () => {
                console.log("Open Start");
            },
            onOpenEnd: () => {
                console.log("Open End");
            },
            onCloseStart: () => {
                console.log("Close Start");
            },
            onCloseEnd: () => {
                console.log("Close End");
            }
        }
    var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
    var instanceModal = M.Modal.init(Modalelem, optionsModal);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately its not working either. I think its not registering the modal at all. It does the same as before with both of your suggestions and all of my trys before. It even works without any modal registration.

Comment: okay then, can you send all your code in a codepen so that we can check?

Comment: I cant copy the exact code but I can try to reconstruct it.

Comment: Sure, what versions of jQuery, materialize are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery 3.3.1 and materialize 1.0.0

Comment: Alright, I added the HTML part, can you try it with that HTML part?

Comment: I just tried it out of my project and it works perfectly fine. I guess i just have to debug my project then. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly haha and for accepting the answer.